# Output from printouts with various backslash escape sequences

Tags: java

I just started in CS 140 and I'm already stuck. The question I'm stuck on is: What is the output produced from the following statements? (Treat tabs as aligning to every multiple of eight spaces.)

```
System.out.println("\\\\");  
System.out.println("'");
System.out.println("\ta\tb\tc");
System.out.println("\"\"\"");
System.out.println("C:\nin\the downward spiral");
```

I programmed this in jGrasp and got:

```
\\
'
    a   b   c
"""
C:
in  he downward spiral
```

When I type this into the website "practice-it" which is where we're supposed to submit our answers, it says: wrong spacing or type. I've tried everything and have no idea where I'm wrong. Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried replacing all the tabs in your answer with eight spaces?

Comment: Is this the first answer you've submitted?  I just went to look at the site and try it out.  I'm getting the same message.  If I change my answer at all, then it gives me a different error.  So it's basically saying that my answer is correct but something about the format is wrong.  I don't get it.  In my case, there are no strange characters like tabs to worry about.  If you change your answer just a little bit, do you get a different error?  If so, then I think you can deduce that your answer is basically correct but officially still wrong for some unknown reason.

Comment: Aziz, I have, practice-it doesn't allow using the tab button so I have to manually type in the amount of spaces. I've tried 8 spaces in between each letter and 8 spaces before a. What I have now is 3 spaces then a space b space c.

Comment: Steve, I've tried every variation of space amounts that I can think of and keep getting the same error message. Maybe it has something to do with the practice-it website?

Comment: If they're going to align on 8 spaces it would be `8 spaces` followed by `a` then `7 spaces` followed by `b` then `7` spaces followed by `c`

Comment: WJS, I was excited to try what you wrote because it makes sense, but it didn't work either...

Comment: Can you paste the text containing `tab` character on practice-it site?

Answer (score 0):

For the tabs, look at it like this.  The letters fall on `1` in the rule.  So the spacing between the letters is 8, 7, and 7.  The space for the last tab would be `6`

```
1234567812345678123456781
        a       b       c

in      he downward spiral
```

Comment: Thank you for this, what you wrote makes sense. I tried this just the way you wrote it but it still doesn't like it. I'm going to screen shot what I have and submit it with a question to the instructor. Thanks everyone for all of your help!!

Comment: Okay, I took a break from staring at this problem, came back to it and realized that I wasn't putting the 6 spaces in between "in" and "he". Now it worked!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and followed the instructions regarding tabs, making sure that each tab became however many spaces it took to have there be an even multiple of 8 characters on the line up to that point.  Here's what I got:

```
        a       b       c
\\
'
"""
C:
in      he downward spiral
```

***This works if you copy/paste it onto the practice-it site***.  So the OP must just not have his spacing right yet. Looks like @WJS's answer would be helpful there. I concur...8, 7, 7, 6 for the space count for each tab.  The OPs result otherwise seems correct.